# Protect Samba with fail2ban?

Tags: fail2ban

I know this isn't the smartest idea, but I use an ssh tunnel to forward samba to my raspberry pi NAS from my server. How can I protect samba against brute force attempts? I couldn't get fail2ban to work, as it complained about not having rules for it in filter.d.

Note: I'm also fine with iptables rules to limite attempts.

Comment: I love fail2ban, but I don't have access to my system to test this out, but looks promising:  http://techtalk.pcpitstop.com/2016/09/15/54418/

Comment: Google search yields - https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fheise.de%2F-3120956&edit-text=

Comment: That only works for Locky

Comment: Modify it so that it works for all of samba lol. You change the expression.

Comment: It only checks for files, I need to monitor brute force attempts

Comment: You will have to modify the regular expression . Really, at the end of the day, you should not be using samba across "the internet", use a different protocol, such as sshfs - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS . Alternately use iptables and block new connections after so many failed attempts. http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/iptables#Additional_Tips scroll down a bit .....